# sending out email alerts - Limit exceeds

Tags: process-builder, limits, email-alert, singleemailmessage

I have a process builder setup which send out an email alert when ever a new records is created. I use dataloader to insert about 40,000 records and after a while I start getting daily email limit has exceeded. This is in sandbox. I did some research and found that email limit is calculated based on number of active user license * 1000 and maximum is 2,000,000.

If I do not have an option to buy enough license to send out 40,000 emails in a day , what are my other options? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to be sending these emails for each record that's created in your data load?

Comment: Yes. For each record an email is sent to the email id specified in an email field on the record.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_email_limits.htm Salesforce is not meant to be a mass email system. If you want that look into ExactTraget or some other email integrations

Comment: Yes , I have a process builder that send email alerts. I checked the sandbox and it has 6000 email limit for a day. I am not using any code as of now.

Comment: Comment updated.

Comment: oh ok. So if I change the process builder to workflow and use it in production env, will I be able to send any number of email alerts per day?

Comment: @SfdcBat - No, not unless you have the User Licenses to support it. I have never had that issue so I had to look into it a bit. Seems you may need an external service and maybe implement outbound messages to trigger an email?

Comment: I guess even out bound messages have a limit of 100 emails I think

Comment: You can create a task for each user instead of sending mail ,since Creating task have no limits.

Comment: @SfdcBat - There is no published limit on outbound messages via WFR

Comment: @SfdcBat Outbound messaging isn't an email, it's an API call to a service you write externally.